# Why does this terminate after line 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do the Intro to Programming Coursera course, and am basically just retyping examples given in the lectures to make sure I understand things.

Usually, this works out pretty well, but now I am stuck with some code that for some reason terminates after line 1, which, well, I don't want it to do.

```
def convert_to_celsius(fahrenheit):
    '''(number) --> number
Return the number of Celsius degrees equivalent to fahrenheit degrees.

>>>convert_to_celsius(32)
0
>>>convert_to_celsius(212)
100
'''
    return (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9
```

Where is this broken? How can I fix it so it runs properly?

Comment: Where is line 1?  What do you want this code to do?

Comment: did you even called the function?

Comment: I think it gets called by doctests... and thats it ...

Comment: Be aware that this code won't work correctly on python 2.x because of the way python 2.x handles division.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little unsure what your problem is here, but I'm guessing that you're defining a function, but never calling it.  In order to call a function, you use it's name, and supply arguments.  e.g.:

```
#This next block defines the function
def convert_to_celsius(fahrenheit):
    return (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9

#call/use the function
result = convert_to_celsius(100)
#print the results
print(result)
```